# Issue with AAD login and sudo

Tags: sudo, pam, azure

We are experiencing a following issue: when we are using **AAD user** with **Azure Active Directory Authentication for Ubuntu** module - it is **not possible to use** neither **sudo** in terminal nor unlock any setting option in gui. **It didn't accept the password.** Could you please help us understand - is it possible to use such functions or not with Azure AD users?

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug, and it seems that it is allready been fixed: https://github.com/ubuntu/aad-auth/issues/197

You ca use this ppa to fix it.
(source: https://github.com/ubuntu/aad-auth/pull/215#issuecomment-1540165671)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:justdenis/aad-sudo-fix
sudo apt update

sudo apt install libpam-aad libnss-aad
```

Would be interesting to know when it finds its way to the apt repos.